# check a directory and its subdirectory and print the path

Tags: python, recursion

I want to write some code to check if a directory (and its subdirectories) matches with a given string, let the string be `New`. And then I want to print the path from root to the specific directory that contains this string `New`. However, my code only prints the directories on the first level correctly, e.g., `C:\\New Folder`, if there is a subdirectory inside that one matches the string as well, for example `C:\\New Folder\\New Folder`, it will only print as `C:\\New Folder`. For more details, please take a look at my code snipet:

```
 import os
 rootDir = 'C:\\New Folder'
 os.chdir(rootDir)
 for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
     for dirs in subdirs:
         splitdirs = dirs.split(" ")
         prefix = "New"
         if splitdirs[0] == prefix:
            newDir = os.path.join(rootDir, dirs)
            print(newDir)
```

so what I want is to print out`C:\\New Folder` and `C:\\New Folder\\New Folder`, instead it gives me `C:\\New Folder` twice. Can anyone explain why this happens? I am new so probably I'm in lack of some programming way of thinking here. Thank you for checking.

Comment: `os.chdir(rootDir)` is redundant

Comment: directory name should contain given prefix or start with it?

Comment: you probably have a typo: use `root` in `os.path.join(...)` instead of `rootDir`

Comment: @AzatIbrakov the directory name should just contain given prefix

Comment: @AzatIbrakov yeah thanks for pointing that out, somehow I did not notice I made a mistake there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only thing you have to change is following line:

```
newDir = os.path.join(rootDir, dirs)
```

to:

```
newDir = os.path.join(root, dirs)
```

---

### Edit

If your searching word already exists in your rootDir, then you can simplify your code as follow:

```
import os
root_dir = 'C:\\New Folder'
searching_word= "New"
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
    current_directory = os.path.basename(root)
    if searching_word in current_directory:
        print(root)
```

Comment: If the "starting point", `rootDir`, is `C:\\New Folder`, does this solution print it? It seem to me that it doesn't...

Comment: Yes you're right, if the searching word already exists in the rootDir it didn't print. I updated my answer for that case.

Answer (score 1):

Don't look in `subdirs`, `os.walk()` works recursively, so you can just use the `root`. You also don't have to `chdir` there.

```
import os
root_dir = 'C:\\New Folder'
prefix = "New"
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
    current_dir = root.split("\\")[-1] #name of current dir
    dirname_splitted = current_dir.split() #split() implies split(" ")
    if dirname_splitted[0] == prefix:
        print(root)
```

Don't know if it works on Windows, but worked on my Ubuntu with `root_dir = "/tmp"` and `root.split("/")`

EDIT: In comments, you say it should just contain the given prefix, not start with it. The code gets a bit simpler then:

```
import os
root_dir = 'C:\\New Folder'
prefix = "New"
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
    current_dir = root.split("\\")[-1] #name of current dir
    if prefix in current_dir:
        print(root)
```

Comment: `root.split("\\")[-1]` is ugly and non-portable, use [`os.path.dirname`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname)

Answer (score 0):

When you define newDir you are using your rootDir, instead of root.
rootDir is your first folder, while root is the path of the current os.walk iteration.

Your code shoud be:

```
import os
rootDir = os.path.join(os.getcwd())
os.chdir(rootDir)
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
    for dirs in subdirs:
        splitdirs = dirs.split(" ")
        prefix = "New"
        if splitdirs[0] == prefix:
            newDir = os.path.join(root, dirs)
            print(newDir)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need this

```
import os
rootDir = 'D:\\New folder'
os.chdir(rootDir)
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
    for dirs in subdirs:
        splitdirs = dirs.split(" ")
        prefix = "New"
        if splitdirs[0] == prefix:
            newDir = os.path.join(root, dirs)
            print(newDir)
```